# Error in data$update_params(params = params) : [LightGBM] [Fatal] Cannot change max_bin after constructed Dataset handle

Tags: r, machine-learning, lightgbm

I downloaded lightgbm package on RStudio and trying to run a model with it.
The script based on the [Retip](https://www.retip.app/).

The function is this :

```
> fit.lightgbm
function (training, testing) 
{
  train <- as.matrix(training)
  test <- as.matrix(testing)
  coltrain <- ncol(train)
  coltest <- ncol(test)
  dtrain <- lightgbm::lgb.Dataset(train[, 2:coltrain], label = train[, 
                                                                     1])
  lightgbm::lgb.Dataset.construct(dtrain)
  dtest <- lightgbm::lgb.Dataset.create.valid(dtrain, test[,2:coltest], label = test[, 1])
  valids <- list(test = dtest)
  params <- list(objective = "regression", metric = "rmse")
  modelcv <- lightgbm::lgb.cv(params, dtrain, nrounds = 5000, 
                              nfold = 10, valids, verbose = 1, early_stopping_rounds = 1000, 
                              record = TRUE, eval_freq = 1L, stratified = TRUE, max_depth = 4, 
                              max_leaf = 20, max_bin = 50)
  best.iter <- modelcv$best_iter
  params <- list(objective = "regression_l2", metric = "rmse")
  model <- lightgbm::lgb.train(params, dtrain, nrounds = best.iter, 
                               valids, verbose = 0, early_stopping_rounds = 1000, record = TRUE, 
                               eval_freq = 1L, max_depth = 4, max_leaf = 20, max_bin = 50)
  print(paste0("End training"))
  return(model)
}
```

However when I'm trying to run the function as in the  [Retip](https://www.retip.app/)

```
lightgbm <- fit.lightgbm(training,testing)
```

There is this Fatal Error:

```
Error in data$update_params(params = params) : 
  [LightGBM] [Fatal] Cannot change max_bin after constructed Dataset handle.
```

Only when changing max_bin to max_bin=255 there is no error.

Went through documentation:

[What is the right way for hyper parameter tuning for LightGBM classification? #1339](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1053)

[[Python] max_bin weird behaviour #1053](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1053)

Any ideas\suggestions to what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was cross-posted to https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4019 and has been answered there.

Construction of the Dataset object in LightGBM handles some important pre-processing steps (see [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924856/lightgbm-intent-of-lightgbm-dataset/66004139#66004139)) that happen before training, and none of the [Dataset parameters](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#dataset-parameters) can be changed after construction.

Passing `max_bin=50` into `lgb.Dataset()` instead of `lgb.cv()` / `lgb.train()` in the original post's code will result in successful training without this error.