# What is the difference between dataset, booster, cvbooster, sequence in lightgbm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am a little confused about these data structure API in lightgbm. My understanding is like:

1. lgb.dataset is common usage to load data from pandas etc.
2. lgb.booster is to load a model you trained before? (not sure)
3. lgb.cvbooster is same as lgb.booster except some details? (not sure)
4. lgb.sequence is 1-dimension dataset like those used in DNN? (not sure)

Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

LightGBM model training begins by transforming raw data into a `Dataset`. To build up such an object incrementally, you ask LightGBM to iterate over chunks of data provided by a `Sequence`.

Training produces a model object called a `Booster`. This object can be saved in text or binary form, and its `predict()` method can be used to create predictions on new data.

LightGBM's R and Python packages contain a function `lgb.cv()` which performs k-fold cross-validation. This function produces a `CVBooster`, an object which contains a list of `Booster` objects (one per fold).

### More Details

**Dataset**

Before training, LightGBM does some one-time preprocessing, like bucketing continuous features into histograms and dropping unsplittable features. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924856/lightgbm-intent-of-lightgbm-dataset/66004139#66004139) for a more detailed description of that.

The `Dataset` class manages that preprocessing. In the `lightgbm` Python package, for example, you can use `lgb.Dataset()` to create one of these objects from a `numpy` array, `scipy` spare array, `pandas` DataFrame, or CSV/TSV file.

`lgb.train()` in the Python package expects to be passed on of these objects. Classes in [the scikit-learn API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api) expect to be passed raw data like `numpy` arrays and creates the `Dataset` for you internally.

**Booster**

The "B" in "LightGBM" stands for "Boosting". The `Booster` class is the core model object for LightGBM. It holds the current state of the model and has methods for doing things like continuing the training process (`.update()`), creating predictions on new data (`.predict()`), and more.

When training a model with the Python package, you can use `lgb.train()` to produce one of these `Booster` objects. If you use [the scikit-learn API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api), the resulting model object will have a `Booster` inside it.

**CVBooster**

The `CVBooster` class does not existing in the core LightGBM C/C++ library. It is specific to wrapper packages like the R and Python packages.

"CV" in `CVBooster` stands for "cross-validation". It's the object produced by the the cross-validation function `lgb.cv()` in the LightGBM Python and R packages.

The `CVBooster` contains an attribute `.boosters`, which is a list of `Booster` objects (one for each fold from k-fold cross validation).

**Sequence**

The `Sequence` object was new as of LightGBM 3.3.0, and as of that release was only supported in the Python package.

The `Sequence` object is a Python class which allows LightGBM to iterate over chunks of raw data to build up a `Dataset` object incrementally.

This object should be used when your raw data are already partitioned into files (e.g. a collection of HDF5 files) or when you are concerned about exceeding the available memory during `Dataset` construction.